# Split list of lines into 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, list, split, biopython

I have set of sequences in a list which looks like this :

```
[agghd,gjg,tomt]
```

How to split it so that my output looks like the following :

```
[[a,g,g,h,d],[g,j,g],[t,o,m,t]]
```

I have done the following code for now :

```
agghd
gjh 
tomt
list2=[]
list2 = [str(sequences.seq).split() for sequences in family]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split a string to characters by calling `list()` on it

```
list1 = ['agghd', 'gjg', 'tomt']
list2 = [list(string) for string in list1]

# output: [['a', 'g', 'g', 'h', 'd'], ['g', 'j', 'g'], ['t', 'o', 'm', 't']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
[[eval(n) for n in str(sequences.seq).split()] for sequences in family]
```